# Javascript/vue shortcut to if any of the array with the key "name" corresponds to "Apple"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

What is the shortcut with this script?

```
<div v-if=" items[items.length - 1].name === 'Apple' || items[items.length - 2].name === 'Apple'  || items[1].name === 'Apple'">
```

it is working but the "Apple" value might place on the third with more than 5 pairs, so I have to list all possible rank.

Comment: idk if thi works in v-if but in js you can `items.some(x => x.name==='Apple')`. ok it should work i checked

Comment: You could map the names and check if the array includes 'Apple'. ex. ```items.map(item=> item.name.toLowerCase()).includes('apple')``` forcing the string to lowercase as a precaution.